# General question about combination with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

I am in trouble with the concept of combination with repetition. I messed up with my book and youtube videos. Can you please explain me the basics of this concept and especially what do n and r actually represent in the formula of combination with repetition. I will be very helpful for me....

Comment: Which formula do you have in mind?

Comment: C(n+r-1, r) ...

Comment: I know r means selection in easy words but what does that exactly mean (if u understand what I am saying)

Answer (score 0):

I know one.

Any selection of r objects from A, where each object can be selected more than once, is called a combination of n objects taken r at a time with repetition. ... Two combinations with repetition are considered identical if they have the same elements repeated the same number of times, regardless of their order.

Comment: Thanks this is nice explaination but I am interested in something like... Like direct way to distinguish between n and r. Like if you are solving questions of this concept then it is pretty difficult to distinguish especially for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have $n$ types of indistinguishable objects and you set up a combination of $r$ objects, where every object can be of any type. The combinations differ only if they differ by number of objects of some type. Thus we can consider the object types as bins where we should distribute our  $r$ balls. To visualize this use the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))
where you arbitrarily permute $n-1$ "walls" and $r$ balls:
$$
o||ooo|o\dots
$$
Obviously the number of such permutations is equal to the number of ways to choose the positions for $r$ balls (or equivalently for $n-1$ walls) among $r+n-1$ possible ones:
$$
\binom{r+n-1}{r}.
$$